Firebase Auth Error - Unity Android build, Editor Fine
I am currently facing a challenging issue with an Android build in Unity, and I am reaching out in hopes that you might offer some guidance or support.
Here is a summary of the situation:
Unity Version: 2022.3.25f1
Firebase SDK: 11.9.0
In the Unity Editor, all functionalities including login, account creation, and logout operate smoothly. However, when testing on the Android build, the application freezes during the login process.
Here are the specifics:
The issue occurs when executing auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync method.
The login attempt does not progress past initial authentication; debug messages intended to signal the method's invocation do not appear.
Efforts to resolve the issue have included:
    public void LogIn()
    {
        output.text = "email : " + email.text + " , pw : " + password.text;*** -> work fine***

        auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email.text, password.text).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            output.text = "SignIn 메서드 진입"; **-> never appear**
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                output.text = "로그인 취소";  **-> never appear**
                return;
            }
        
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                output.text = "로그인 실패";  **-> never appear**
                return;
            }
            
            output.text = "로그인 완료";  **-> never appear**
            AuthResult result = task.Result;
            FirebaseUser newUser = result.User;
            LogInState?.Invoke(true);
            SceneManager.LoadScene("1.Lobby");
        
        });
    }

Reinstalling the editor
Performing clean and rebuild operations
Resetting Firebase configurations
Verifying architecture settings (ARM64 and IL2CPP)
Ensuring all necessary internet and keystore settings are configured
Registering SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys
Despite these efforts, the problem persists, and I am unable to proceed past the login phase on Android, while no issues arise within the Unity Editor.
Any insights or suggestions you could provide would be immensely valuable. Could this issue be related to a specific configuration within Unity or Firebase that I might have overlooked?
Please Help...
